# Granting permission on a particular job to execute on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

An user is requesting permission on a particular job. How can I give him access on job activity monitor which shows only that requested job?

Comment: you want to grant him access on specific job history or he can modify job?

Comment: User need access on that job, he can modify and run too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add role member `SQLAgentUserRole` in msdb, the user will receive access only to the local (owned) jobs.

-- Step 1

```
CREATE LOGIN [AgentJobUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'1234', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[msdb], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
, CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

--Step 2

```
USE [msdb]
GO
CREATE USER [AgentJobUser] FOR LOGIN [AgentJobUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

-- Step 3

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'SQLAgentUserRole', N'AgentJobUser'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

> User need access on that job, he can modify and run too.

You can give the user - `SQLAgentUserRole`.

From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283(v=sql.90).aspx) :

> SQLAgentUserRole is the least privileged of the SQL Server Agent fixed database roles. It has permissions on only operators, local jobs, and job schedules. Members of SQLAgentUserRole have permissions on only local jobs and job schedules that they own.

```
-- lists activity for all jobs that the current user has permission to view.
USE msdb ;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_help_jobactivity ;
GO
```